# ElementaryOS Horus 7.1 Performance issues

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpu, elementary-os, radeon

I am running ElementaryOS Horus 7.1 and until some point, it ran perfectly well (for my class of hardware). But, eventually, today in the morning I discovered my system being laggy, and overall frustrating to use - all apps: VSCode, Google Chrome, Spotify.

I updated the packages, but nothing changed. Since I have had this problem a couple of months ago and then it was a GPU-related problem, I decided to check if GPU drivers are ok (lsmod | grep "radeon" and radeontop). They were. But I am 100% sure that since this morning, my usage experience had a huge drop.

Linux kernel version: 6.2.0-37-generic

Integrated GPU: **Intel® HD Graphics 4400** (Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller)

Discrete GPU: **AMD Radeon HAINAN** (Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile])

RAM: 12 GB (I am pretty sure that's enough)

I test my GPU performance here: https://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark/

And sometimes track which GPU Chrome uses here: https://hardwaretester.com/gpu

When I discovered pixijs Bunnymark to give me insanely low values, I set DRI_PRIME in /etc/environment. After that, pixijs Bunnymark was ok, but the overall lag of system still took place.

Feel free to ask questions about my problem (I think I specified all that is needed to understand what is happening, but I might have skipped something)